# Orphaned headings in a long, verse-heavy document

Tags: sectioning, verse, widows-orphans

I'm typesetting an anthology of English poetry which I've put together. It's a long document, **more than 500 pages**, and the nature of the project means that the vast majority of the text is wrapped up in about a thousand **verse** environments. While I've managed to get the typesetting mostly how I want it, there are still about two dozen **orphaned headings**, which I would like to resolve.

This is the code for a **minimal working example** of the problem:

```latex
\documentclass{amsbook}

\title{Hosker's Almanack}

\usepackage{verse, xfrac}

% Fix fractions.
\usepackage{xfrac}
\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{cmunrm.otf(0)}{text}{
    slash-symbol-font = ptm,
    scale-factor=0.8,
    numerator-top-sep = 0pt,
    denominator-bot-sep = 0pt,
    slash-right-kern=-.25em,
    slash-left-kern=-.3em
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\renewcommand\thesection{{\Roman{section}}}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{{\thesubsection.}}
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{{{{\@thefnmark}}}}\hbox{{{{ }}}}}
\makeatother

\part{The Almanack Proper}

\chapter{Primilis}

\bigskip
\bigskip
\section{}

\subsection{}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{{\vin} {\vin} A burning forehead, and a parching tongue.}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Thou still unravished bride of quietness,\\*\footnotetext{`Ode on a Grecian Urn', John Keats (1795 -- 1821)}
{\vin} Thou foster-child of silence and slow time,\\
Sylvan historian, who canst thus express\\
{\vin} A flowery tale more sweetly than our rhyme:\\
What leaf-fringed legend haunts about thy shape\\
{\vin} Of deities or mortals, or of both,\\
{\vin} {\vin} In \textsc{Tempe} or the dales of Arcady?\\
{\vin} What men or gods are these? What maidens loth?\\
What mad pursuit? What struggle to escape?\\*
{\vin} {\vin} What pipes and timbrels? What wild ecstasy?\\!

Heard melodies are sweet, but those unheard\\*
{\vin} Are sweeter; therefore, ye soft pipes, play on;\\
Not to the sensual ear, but, more endeared,\\
{\vin} Pipe to the spirit ditties of no tone:\\
Fair youth, beneath the trees, thou canst not leave\\
{\vin} Thy song, nor ever can those trees be bare;\\
{\vin} {\vin} Bold lover, never, never canst thou kiss,\\
Though winning near the goal yet, do not grieve;\\
{\vin} She cannot fade, though thou hast not thy bliss,\\*
{\vin} {\vin} For ever wilt thou love, and she be fair!\\!

Ah, happy, happy boughs, that cannot shed\\*
{\vin} Your leaves, nor ever bid the spring adieu;\\
And, happy melodist, unwearied,\\
{\vin} For ever piping songs for ever new;\\
More happy love! more happy, happy love!\\
{\vin} For ever warm and still to be enjoyed,\\
{\vin} {\vin} For ever panting, and for ever young;\\
All breathing human passion far above,\\
{\vin} That leaves a heart high-sorrowful and cloyed,\\*
{\vin} {\vin} A burning forehead, and a parching tongue.\\!

Who are these coming to the sacrifice?\\*
{\vin} To what green altar, O mysterious priest,\\
Lead'st thou that heifer lowing at the skies,\\
{\vin} And all her silken flanks with garlands drest?\\
What little town by river or sea shore,\\
{\vin} Or mountain-built with peaceful citadel,\\
{\vin} {\vin} Is emptied of this folk, this pious morn?\\
And, little town, thy streets for evermore\\
{\vin} Will silent be; and not a soul to tell\\*
{\vin} {\vin} Why thou art desolate, can e'er return.\\!

O attic shape! Fair attitude! with brede\\*
{\vin} Of marble men and maidens overwrought,\\
With forest branches and the trodden weed;\\
{\vin} Thou, silent form, dost tease us out of thought\\
As doth eternity: cold pastoral!\\
{\vin} When old age shall this generation waste,\\
{\vin} {\vin} Thou shalt remain, in midst of other woe\\
Than ours, a friend to man, to whom thou say'st,\\
{\vin} `Beauty is truth, truth beauty -- that is all\\*
{\vin} {\vin} Ye know on earth, and all ye need to know.'
FILLER\\
FILLER\\
FILLER\\
FILLER\\
FILLER\\
FILLER\\
FILLER\\
FILLER\\
FILLER\\
\end{verse}

\subsection{}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{{\vin} He stared at the Pacific -- and all his men}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Much have I travelled in the realms of gold,\\*\footnotetext{`On First Looking into Chapman's Homer', John Keats (1795 -- 1821).}
{\vin} And many goodly states \& kingdoms seen;\\
{\vin} Round many western islands have I been\\
Which bards in fealty to \textit{Apollo} hold.\\
Oft of one wide expanse had I been told\\
{\vin} That deep-browed \textit{Homer} ruled as his demesne,\\
{\vin} Yet did I never breathe its pure serene\\
Till I heard \textit{Chapman} speak out loud \& bold.\\
Then felt I like some watcher of the skies\\
{\vin} When a new planet swims into his ken;\\
Or like stout \textit{Cortez}, when with eagle eyes\\
{\vin} He stared at the Pacific -- and all his men\\
Looked at each other with a wild surmise --\\*
{\vin} Silent, upon a peak in Darien.
\end{verse}

\subsection{}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{Let the dead bury their dead.}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Let the dead bury their dead.\footnotetext{Matthew 8.22}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

And this is a screenshot of what the problem looks like when I compile the above code:

[image]

Comment: latex headings normally prevent a pagebreak following, so as you haven't shown any code it is not really possible to say anything. You need to not do whatever is allowing a page break at that point, but hard to guess what that is

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I strongly suspect that the pagebreak is caused by the fact that all the text in each section is in a `verse` environment. I think LaTeX treats a special environment like that differently than a block of the normal prose. That's what I'm trying to solve. But I will post some code all the same.

Comment: the code is still not usable, the standard verse enviroment does not have an optional argument, so this is some uknown code we can not debug

Comment: In the snippets shown, each verse is preceded by `\subsection{}`.  I think that is what needs to be adjusted to favor going to a new page.  Perhaps building in `\needspace` would help.  But since sectioning is defined differently in different document classes, I can't offer more specific ideas.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can feel your frustration. What code would you like me to post? I doubt you want me to post all 20,000 lines of the actual source code! I anticipate you're about to ask for a MWE, but I'm stuggling to imagine what that would look like. Orphaned headings only tend to crop up in longer documents. Would it be helpful if I posted the pre-`begin{document}` code?

Comment: I don't mind if you post anything but currently all you have said is that some unshown code produces a page break. You can provide a complete two page document that shows the problem: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\begin{verse}a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\end{verse}\subsection{}\begin{verse}a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\end{verse}\end{document}` modified accordingly

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. That's really helpful. I've amended the question to include the MWE that (I hope!) you were fishing for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`verse` package `verse` is a display environment made up of a one item trivlist.

As such the penalty for breaking before the verse is the penalty for breaking before an `\item` so it is negative (-51) denoting a good place to break.

You could set this to 10000 so it would be maximally bad to break at that point. Locally, or if there are no lists where you do not want this setting, you can set it in the preamble.

The above was set as in your example, with the addition of

```
\makeatletter

\@beginparpenalty=10000

\makeatother
```

before `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps adding some space and glue before and after the `\subsection` helps to solve the issue. (It does with this MWE, it must be tried with the real document)

Values taken from the class `book`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\normalparindent}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Put it before `\begin{document}`.

To test the sensitivity:

(1) Try it with  nine `FILLER\\` lines: the full I.3 subsection goes to the next page.

(2) Remove one or two `FILLER\\` lines: the full I.3 subsection still goes to the next page.

(3) Then delete three: the entire subsection I.3 remains on the same  page together with I.2.

(4) Finally test with eleven `FILLER\\` lines. The full I.2 remains in the page.

Original MWE 9 `FILLER\\` lines

[image: a9]

With 7 `FILLER\\` lines

[image: b7]

With 6 `FILLER\\` lines

[image: c6]